# Overcome resource/.axml difficulties in HelloWorld Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am starting out in Xamarin to create an Android app for the first time, so I am following the most basic [Xamarin Android tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,_world/).  I get to the point where I am editing my Strings.xml file for my UI controls. I do so, and compile, and get:

```
C:\...\main.xml(0,0): Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello'). (AndroidHello)
```

I don't have a main.xml, but I do have a Main.axml, which was apparently generated with the solution.  Am I expected to edit this file to match my .cs files?  That doesn't seem right at all.  Or should it be re-generated from the .cs somehow?

I searched around to try to understand more about .axml files, so I understand that they can be used to specify a layout, instead of doing so in C# code.  So I thought I could just delete the .axml file and rely on C# only--but then my Resource.String.whatever resources that I specified in Strings.xml won't work when referenced from my C# code.

Strings.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="helloButtonText">Say Hello</string>
<string name="helloLabelText">Hello Xamarin.Android</string>
</resources>
```

As mentioned, the .axml file references strings that no longer exist.  How should I resolve that?

Comment: Please, add the code of you layout and string.xml file

Comment: You should have main.xml as the error says x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the following Button defined in the main.axml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello" />
```

Replace the @string/Hello and you should be good to go. If you changed the string.xml then "@string/helloButtonText" might be the replacement you need, or simply "Say Hello".

Comment: Am I expected to edit this file to match my .cs files?

Comment: No you should not have to. The @string prefix refers to a resource generated from the string.xml file. As I see you changed the names of the resources you should now change the layout file to match these changes.

Comment: This isn't adding up for me conceptually.  Shouldn't I somehow regenerate the layout file rather than manually editing it?

Comment: No, you don't generate layout files, you create them. This means editing either manually or with the layout editor. Look at the tutorial under "Creating the User Interface with XML"